# stitch/ Rstudio Compile notebook: modify default fig width, height?

Tags: html, r, knitr, rstudio, figure

In RStudio, the Compile notebook feature is very handy, but I'd like to be able to change the default
figure width and height globally for a given .R script.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

According to [RStudio documentation](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_notebooks), there are two possible notebook types at the moment. To achieve what you want, you have to choose the type `knitr::spin`, which allows you to change chunk options; see [knitr documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/stitch/) for details.

In this case, you just add a code chunk to set up chunk options, e.g.,

```
#+ setup, include=FALSE
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 5, fig.height = 10)

#' write the rest of your code
1 + 1
rnorm(10)
plot(cars)
```

[image: knitr spin]

Comment: That's what I was missing -- how to use markdown comments to set chunk options.